# How to show String in another Form of label

Tags: c#, forms, label

I have Form1. In this Form I have Label.After that I have another Class in this class  I want to use the **label of Form1**.I use this CodeFinance fin = new Finance();`

```
            fin.lbl_mnth.Text = month;`
```

1. Finance is **FirstForm**
2. lbl_mnth is **Label**
3. month is **String**
   But this Cant work.How to show this String into this Current Class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Best thing is this which I use declare label and send label in `class2.fun(Label)
public void fun(Lable label){
lbalel.Text="Hellow"}`

Answer (score 1):

Code below shows you how to do it:

```
public partial class FormA:Form
{
    ...
    public Label lbl_mnth;
    public FormA()
    {
          lbl_mnth = new Label();
          lbl_mnth.Name = "lbl_mnth";
          ...
          this.Controls.Add(lbl_mnth);
    }
}
public partial class Form1:Form
{
    ...
    private void button1_Click(...)
    {
           FormA a = new FormA();
           var labelControl = a.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList().Where(x=>x.Name == "lbl_mnth").FirstOrDefault();
           if (labelControl != null)
               labelControl.Text = "Blah Blah";
    }
}
```